# connector lines in scatter chart nvd3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, charts, nvd3.js

i am drawing nvd3 scatter chart and i want to connect each circle to each other such like we have line chart with circles.
my chart: [image]

here is the code i wrote:

```
    function scatterChartConfig(con, data, labels) {
    $(con).show().find('.spark-chart').show();
    var div = '#' + $(con).find('.spark-chart').attr('id');
    $(div).empty().data({
        'lineChart': false
    });

    $('#brush').hide();

    nv.addGraph(function() {
        $(div).height("68vh")
        var height = $(div).height(),
            width = height, // a square chart
            chart = nv.models.scatterChart()
            .interactive(true)
            .tooltips(true)
            .showDistX(true)
            .showDistY(true)
            .transitionDuration(350)
            .tooltipContent(function(key, x, y, obj) {
                console.log(obj);
                return ' RPM (' + obj.point.size.toFixed(2) + ')';
            });

       //chart.xAxis.axisLabel(labels.x).tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'));
        chart.yAxis.axisLabel(labels.y).axisLabelDistance(20).tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'));

        //We do no want to show shapes other than circles.
        chart.scatter.onlyCircles(true);

        d3.select(div).append('svg')
            .datum(data)
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height)
            .call(chart);

        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

        return chart;
    });

}
```

i want to do it with js or i can update the nvd3.js library no css solution.

Comment: You would have to change the NVD3 source code for this. Probably better to do it in plain D3.

Comment: i am not expert in d3. although i Have study nvd3 library completely and understand how its work.. before doing this by library i am looking for any generic solution.